# Fundamental group of a bouquet of circles

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Consider a bouquet of $n$ circles, centered at $(1,0), (2,0),...,(n,0)$ $$ W_n= \bigcup_1^nC_r$$ with $$C_r:(x-r)^2+y^2=r^2$$

I want to compute the fundamental group of this space.

> $W_n$ is path connected. Moreover I know
> $\pi_1(W_1)=\pi_1(C_1)=\mathbb{Z}.$ Seeing $W_n= W_{n-1}\cup C_n$ we
> have both $W_{n-1}$ and $C_n$ are path connected and open. Moreover
> $W_{n-1} \cap C_n $ is just the origin which has trivial fundamental
> group. Hence
> $$\pi(W_n)=\pi(W_{n-1})*\pi(C_1)=\pi(W_{n-1})*\mathbb{Z}=...=\pi_1(W_1)*\mathbb{Z}...*\mathbb{Z}=$$$$\pi(C_1)*\mathbb{Z}*...*\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}*...*\mathbb{Z}$$
> so it is the $n$-times free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself.

Does it work? First I want to know if my solution is correct and only secondly a different one thanks.

Comment: **Hint :** use Van Kampen's theorem to get that the wedge sum of $n$ circles has fundamental group $F_n$. Use induction.

Comment: @AnthonySaint-Criq thanks but the question is not how to do it, but what is wrong with my answer.

Comment: You changed the question to invalidate the answer that explained what was wrong with your solution. Please don't do that.

Comment: @LeeMosher This is not true. I just realized I wrongly took $\mathbb{Z}^n$ for $\mathbb{Z}*...*\mathbb{Z}$ and no answer pointed that out. They say $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is abelian but it would have been obvious to anyone taking a second to read the answer that I was just confused about the free product, so it wasnt the real reason why my answer would be wrong

Comment: I have to agree that addressing a typo is not the same as changing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct but a bit sloppy. It is true that the sets $W_{n-1}$ and $C_1$ are path-connected, but they are not open. Clearly no real harm has occured, but you should be careful to meet the requirements of the exact statement of the Seifert-van Kampen Theorem which you clearly applying.

The space $W_n$ is a wedge of $n$ circle $\vee^nS^1$. There are slight more sophisticated van Kampen Theorems which can compute the fundamental group of such spaces directly (i.e. by working with a family of many path-connected open sets and their intersections rather than just two).

Another way to compute its fundamental group is to construct its universal cover. There is a standard way to describe the universal covers of wedge sums. The case for $n=1,2$ is clear, but I don't even want to think about what the space looks like for higher $n$.

Comment: Yes I know it can be done also with yet another version of Van Kampen where you divide the space into two pieces where one the the two is simply connected and the intersection is not path connected but can be obtained as the disjoint union of two simply connected pieces. What I wanted to know is precisely why it could not be done with the "standard" version of van kampen. The fact that the two pieces are not open answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: @ggeolier what I was referring to was the van Kampen theorem stated in May's *A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology* $\S2.7$ where you would cover $W_n$ by $n$ path connected open subsets $U_i$, each containing the basepoint, and recognise $\pi_1W_n$ as $colim_{i=1,\dots,n}\;\pi_1U_i$. You can also read any of Ronnie Brown's books for a statement of the more sophisticated theorem.

Answer (score -5):

Your answer is wrong, for example, it is not very difficult to see that this fundamental group is not abelian. A way to compute that is to show that the space $W_n$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of $n$ circles and then use the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem to show that its fundamental group is the free group with $n$ generators.

Comment: I wrongly took $\mathbb{Z}^{n}$ for the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself $n$ times, which I now changed to $\mathbb{Z}*...*\mathbb{Z}.$ Except this what is wrong with what I did?

Comment: You should not change the question to invalidate the given answers.

Comment: @LeeMosher I did not change the question to invalidate an answer. I changed the question because I wrongly wrote the free product of $\mathbb{Z}$ with itself $n$ times.

Comment: @ggeolier, you change your question to invalidate my answer, under this conditions I cannot do further comments about the 'modified' question

Comment: @MarioVelásquez If you really think that changing from $\pi(W_{n-1})*\mathbb{Z}=\pi(W_1)*\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ to $\pi(W_1)*\mathbb{Z}*...*\mathbb{Z}$  changed the question rather than addressing a trivial confusion then it means that you did not actually read the question before answering it.